# locale issues on web server

Tags: linux, ubuntu

My website was moved to a new web server recently.

Its now on Ubuntu 9.04 and when I run

```
locale
```

it returns:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

What does the error mean and how do I fix it? I did think it was something to do with libc6 but have since reinstalled it and it hasn't made a difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

try dpkg-reconfigure locales.